# Java Bean Validation (JSR303) constraints involving relationship between several bean properties

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Say I have the following simple java bean:

```
class MyBean {
   private Date startDate;
   private Date endDate;
   //setter, getters etc...
}
```

Is there a mechanism in JSR 303 to create a custom validator that validates the constraint that startDate must be before endDate?

It seems to me to be a common use case, yet I cannot find any examples of this kind of multiple property relationsship constraint.

Comment: It seams that someone posted a complete example in his blog: http://soadev.blogspot.de/2010/01/jsr-303-bean-validation_29.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I can think of a few things to try.

You could create a `Constraint` with a target of the type itself with an appropriate validator:

```
@ValidateDateRange(start="startDate", end="endDate")
public class MyBean {
```

You could encapsulate a date range in a type and validate that:

```
public class DateRange {    
  private long start;
  private long end;

  public void setStart(Date start) {
    this.start = start.getTime();
  }

  // etc.
```

You could add a simple property that performs the check:

```
public class MyBean {
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;

  @AssertTrue public boolean isValidRange() {
    // TODO: null checks
    return endDate.compareTo(startDate) >= 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're using [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) in version 4.1 or later you can use the [@ScriptAssert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html) constraint together with a scripting or expression language to express this kind of constraint. Using JavaScript your example would look like this:

```
 @ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.startDate.before(_this.endDate)")
 public class CalendarEvent {

      private Date startDate;

      private Date endDate;

      //...
 }
```

You can get an even more compact syntax by [creating a custom constraint](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/06/whats-new-in-hibernate-validator-41.html) for the script language of your choice:

```
@JexlAssert("_.startDate < _.endDate")
public class CalendarEvent {

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a class level validator. You can define custom constraints which you can place on entity class. At validation time you get passed the whole instance into the isValid() method. You can then compare your two dates against each other. See also the Hibernate Validator [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e328).

Answer (score 1):

[@AssertMethodAsTrue - A reusable constraint annotation that spans multiple properties.](http://soadev.blogspot.com/2010/01/jsr-303-bean-validation.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -5):

Since there is no way to access the bean in a JSR 303 validator, this is not possible.

A workaround would be to supply your own `ConstraintValidatorContext` and extend it with a reference to the bean you're currently validating. But I'm not sure whether you can modify/override the respective factory.